# conjugate operation on vector bundle

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Is the conjugate operation on $\overset{\sim}{K}(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n)$ known? If so, can I get the full formula at least in terms of the basis $\eta^i$? Here $\overset{\sim}{K}(X)$ denotes the reduced stable isomorphic classes of complex vector bundles over X. And conjugation operation on $\overset{\sim}{K}(x)$ is induced from the conjugate operation on complex vector bundles. And $\eta=H-1$ where $H$ is the canonical complex line bundle over $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n.$

Comment: please give more context. What is $\tilde{K}$?

Comment: @ Dima Pasenchnik, I thought these are commonly used notations, that's why I didn't give the meanings of them.

Comment: Complex conjugation is the Adams operation $\Psi^{-1}$. This is determined for complex projective space in Theorem 7.2 of Adams' paper "Vector fields on spheres", Ann of Math 75 (1962), 603-632.

Comment: The conjugate of $H$ is $H^{-1}$.  The conjugate of $\eta$ follows from that: it is $(1+\eta)^{-1}-1$.

Comment: @Neil Strickland, I missed that point. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @Matthias Wendt for mentioning the theorem no. in that paper of Adams. Thank you everyone.